# Checking for E-Mail in calabash

Tags: email, calabash, calabash-android

Is there any way to check if I have received an E-Mail (For example after registration) with certain text using calabash-android?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should try to show your code. Please take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Well, there's no code other than perhaps a simple line saying "Then I should get a new e-mail"

Answer (score 2):

Calabash is made to interact with mobile apps. However you can hit an API of a mail service using Ruby in your calabash project, that is the best solution I'd say. Gmail would be the most stable option ([gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/)), but there are others, e.g. https://www.mailinator.com/.